# Refactoring multiple boolean conditions?

Tags: java, object-oriented, design-patterns

I have a Predicate which takes employee object.

```
Predicate<Employee> getPredicate() {
    return emp -> filter(emp);
}
```

Now the filter method is very complex, it calls four other methods which returns true/false if all the conditions are true, the `predicate` will return true.

```
private boolean filter(Employee employee) {
    String employeeJSONString = employeeToString(employee);
    return filterBasedOnConsistAge(employeeJSONString) && 
           filterBasedOnConsistGender(employeeJSONString) &&
           filterBasedOnConsistNationality(employeeJSONString) &&
           filterBasedOnConsistHandicap(employeeJSONString);
}

private String employeeToString(Employee employee) {
    // converts domainObject to a formatted string, it's a business requirement
}
```

There are five-line methods, that are linked using logical AND. But the problem here is, the chaining is looking clean. is there a way to improve this logic?

Comment: Your function names make me fear for the worst.

Comment: Please don't change the code in your question after it's answered - it makes the answers seem nonsensical.  You could post improved code as a new question, as an answer, or as a link to an external site - as described in [I improved my code based on the reviews. What next?](/help/someone-answers#help-post-body).  I have rolled back the edit, so the answers make sense again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What especially jumps at me is, that you take your real data object (the Employee), convert it to a *string representation* and do your checks on the string.

Why? Can't you check your data object?

Apart from that, I don't see a problem with 5 and-conditions. This is clearer to read than some clever stream-through-predicates-and-reduce code. Clear. Simple. Leave it like that.

What I'd recommend is rethinking your naming:

- `getPredicate()`: yes, it returns a predicate, we see that from the method signature. But *what* does this predicate test?
- `filter()`: does some filtering, but according *to which criteria*?

(Sorry to pepijno, I typed this without seeing your answer... no offense meant ;-))

Comment: @mtj non taken ;)

Comment: @GovindaSakhare business requirements should not be dictating your implementation choice. What is the REST service (value-)adding into the `String` representation? Perhaps you should even consider deserializing that representation to some kind of  `EnrichedEmployee` class and perform the filtering on that data object. String-based filtering is brittle and can be *easily* undone with data quality issues such as a stray delimiter.

Answer (score 10):

Each one of the `filterBasedOnConsist*` methods look like they would be individual predicates themselves. So convert each method into a `Predicate` class and use the default `and` method to chain them together into a composite predicate:

```
Predicate<String> employeePredicate =
    new FilterBasedOnConsistAge()
    .and(new FilterBasedOnConsistGender())
    .and(new FilterBasedOnConsistNationality())
    .and(new FilterBasedOnConsistHandicap())
```

Use a more descriptive name than `employeePredicate`. I have no idea what you are using it for so I just put a bad generic name there.

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to do it with `Stream`s. This is assuming that all different filters are in the same class as the `filter` method:

```java
private boolean filter(Employee employee) {
  Stream<Predicate<String>> filters = Stream.of(
    this::filterBasedOnConsistAge,
    this::filterBasedOnConsistGender,
    this::filterBasedOnConsistNationality,
    this::filterBasedOnConsistHandicap
  );

  String employeeJSONString = employeeToString(employee);
  return filters.allMatch(f -> f.test(employeeJSONString));
}
```

The `allMatch` method of `Stream` returns `true` if the condition is true for all elements in the `Stream` and `false` otherwise.

Comment: This seems like a fairly inefficient way to reimplement the Predicate.and(...) method.

Comment: @TorbenPutkonen you are probably right, I forgot about the Predicate.and(...) method